# Referencing a dynamic argument in the Docker Entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, quoting, duplicity-backup

I want to run a docker container like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v volume1:/target -v volume2:/backup duplicity-image backup-label
```

This would cause the following Entrypoint do get executed:

```
duplicity /target file:///backup/$backup-label
```

So my question is how do I structure the ENTRYPOINT such that it can resolve the `$backup-label` and how do I pass the `backup-label` in ... Do I need single quotes around it ... a dash in front of it ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an `ENTRYPOINT` script in your image, that script will receive any arguments passed after the image on the `docker run` command line.  That is, if you have:

```
ENTRYPOINT /path/to/my/script.sh
```

And you run:

```
docker run myimage one two three
```

Your `ENTRYPOINT` script will be called like:

```
/path/to/my/script.sh one two three
```

From that point on, it's just like writing any other shell script that takes arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

backup_label=$1
duplicity /target file:///backup/$backup_label
```