# Referencing the first argument passed to the docker entrypoint?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to obtain the value of the first argument I pass to the Docker Entrypoint.  I received an answer earlier on how to do this.  Here is the link:

[Referencing a dynamic argument in the Docker Entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324541/referencing-a-dynamic-argument-in-the-docker-entrypoint)

So I setup an experiment to see if this works:

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3
MAINTAINER ole.ersoy@gmail.com

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --no-progress bash
COPY run.sh .
ENTRYPOINT /run.sh
```

And the `run.sh` entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo The first argument is: $1
```

I then build this:

```
docker build -t test .
```

And run the image:

```
ole@MKI:~/docker-test$ docker run test one
The first argument is:
```

I was expecting:

```
ole@MKI:~/docker-test$ docker run test one
The first argument is: one
```

Thoughts?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ENTRYPOINT to next:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "run.sh"]
```

It works for me. Read more about entrypoint args here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint